Django, mySQL, macOS
На моем мак установлен mysql с официального сайта, я мно работал с ним в процессе обучения через dbeaver, никаких проблем не наблюдалось.
Теперь когда я начал изучать фремворк Django я хочу подключать свой проект к mysql (локально).
Конфигурация в проекте
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root'
    }
}

Но при создании нового приложения с помощью python3 manage.py startapp my_app (все запускается из правильной папки проекта) на выводе текст

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
line 16, in 
import MySQLdb as Database ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/movie_project/manage.py", line
22, in 
main()   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/movie_project/manage.py", line
18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py",
line 442, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py",
line 416, in execute
django.setup()   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/init.py",
line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
line 116, in populate
app_config.import_models()   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
line 269, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/init.py",
line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "", line 1387, in _gcd_import   File
"", line 1360, in _find_and_load   File
"", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 935, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 999, in
exec_module   File "", line 488, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
line 5, in 
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File
"/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
line 40, in 
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
line 143, in new
new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
line 371, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
line 231, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
line 15, in getattr
return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
line 62, in getitem
conn = self.create_connection(alias)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 193, in create_connection
backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 113, in load_backend
return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/init.py",
line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
line 18, in 
raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Как я понял он не может использовать mysqlclient
Нашел что нужно установить дополнителный модуль
pip install mysqlclient

Но и здесь получаю текс с ошибкой

Collecting mysqlclient   Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz (91 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build
wheel ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Trying pkg-config --exists perconaserverclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists perconaserverclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 353, in 
main()
File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/4izhyk/Documents/Python/Django/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py",
line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/1w/st75q7td5v91z_w064jbltlc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0jenqrxn/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/1w/st75q7td5v91z_w064jbltlc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0jenqrxn/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 304, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/1w/st75q7td5v91z_w064jbltlc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-0jenqrxn/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
line 320, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 155, in 
File "", line 49, in get_config_posix
File "", line 28, in find_package_name
Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit
code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.

Как же подружить mysql и django?
Использую django 5, mysql 9.0.1, macOS 12.7, python 3.12.8
Проблема установки pip install mysqlclient решилась.
Проблема при создании нового приложения с помощью python3 manage.py startapp my_app все еще осталась
Проблема не решается, перелопатил весь интернет.
Пришлось конектиться к postgresql, в нем все заработало хоть и были некие проблемы.

Как минимум прочитать инструкцию по установке https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/main/README.md#macos-homebrew

команда
brew install mysql pkg-config завершилась  с ошибкой
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mymac/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/baee7eae7d4f57c065a4bb4da48fb7f2b852a4d975518daeb47671f507aaf337--mpdecimal--4.0.0.monterey.bottle.1.tar.gz
Далее pip install mysqlclient снова с той же ошибкой что и раньше? Есть предположения что это и как исправить?

Попробуйте brew doctor, затем brew cleanup, вдруг да поможет чем.

Это не помогает. Если я правильно понимаю но не загружается модуль django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.

в doker контейнере может сразу пробовать, всё равно же потом на сервере разворачивать

друг я пока учусь. что такое doker только отдаленно знаю.

Тебе критично использовать mysql? Я бы советовал использовать Posgresql. Он довольно круто работает с джанго

Спасибо. Уже так и сделал. Но все же хотелось бы разобраться в проблеме так сказать на будущее.
